# Python 3 variable list difference

Tags: python

I have have two list and and I am trying to compare differences in $ amount over a certain amount.

the list are

```
file1 = ['file1,product1,-1000.56', 'file1,product2,500.43']

file2 = ['file2,product1,-1001.37', 'file2,product2,511.99']
```

I want to print the differences if over $5 in the below format

```
file1 product2 500.43
file2 product2 511.99

Difference = $11.56
```

Product 1 won't display because it's less than $5

Is there a good way to do this?

I have tried...

```
for i in file1:
    i.split(",")
```

This works to get the list split out but how to I compare the two $ amounts, and display only $5 or more.

If someone could give me a way to compare the two $ amounts over $5 difference I can prob figure out the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `zip()` to traverse over both lists:

```
In [114]: file1 = ['file1,product1,-1000.56', 'file1,product2,500.43']

In [115]: file2 = ['file2,product1,-1001.37', 'file2,product2,511.99']

In [116]: for f1,f2 in zip(file1,file2):
    spl1=f1.split(',')     #returns something like ['file1', 'product2', '500.43']
    spl2=f2.split(',')     #returns something like ['file2', 'product2', '511.99']

    diff=abs(float(spl1[-1])-float(spl2[-1]))  ##use abs() to find the difference

    if diff>5:  
        print " ".join(spl1)                    #use print() as you're on py 3.x 
        print " ".join(spl2)                    #join the lists by " " 
        print "${0}".format(diff)
   .....:         
   .....:         
file1 product2 500.43
file2 product2 511.99
$11.56
```

Comment: @AdamG Note that this only works if your two lists are *in the same order*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned in identical products that occur in both files, then you can create a dict of product->value lookup, and then take the difference between the files (untested and could be made more elegant):

```
file1 = ['file1,product1,-1000.56', 'file1,product2,500.43']
file2 = ['file2,product1,-1001.37', 'file2,product2,511.99']

d1 = {k: float(v) for k, v in (el.split(',')[1:] for el in file1)}
d2 = {k: float(v) for k, v in (el.split(',')[1:] for el in file2)}

for key in d1.keys() & d2.keys():
    print (key, abs(d1[key] - d2[key]))

# product2 11.56
# product1 0.81
```

Answer (score 0):

After you split on the comma, the last element will be a string that represents a dollar amount.  The first step is to convert this to a number using [`float`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float).  After you have two dollar amounts as floats, you can just subtract them and compare to `5.0`, for example:

```
diff = abs(float('511.99') - float('500.43'))
if diff >= 5.0:
    # print it
```

Note that I also used the built-in function [`abs`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#abs) to make sure we got a positive difference, that way you don't need to figure out which value is bigger first.